# Why calling many anonym functions is so slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, optimization, view, lambda

From database I am loading about 1000 of rows.

I have a class for printing a table. In view I define some rules, almost for each column, for example:

```
<% table.rules :date_uzp, lambda { |row| l row.date_uzp if row.date_uzp.present? } %>
<% table.rules :another_column, lambda { |row| helper_method row } %>
```

And in the end, I just call <%= table.print %>, and it generates html for table.

Why I need to have a special class for generating tables? Tables are really specific in this project, so to follow principles of DRY, I have class for it..

But there is a problem, if I process almost all columns and call anonym function on them, it's so slow. (anonym function is called about 10 000 times, i know, it's quite a lot but it can't be so slow) Page is loading about 50s.

Where is a problem? What do you suggest?

Comment: Have you bechmarked it? Why are you sure it is about lambdas, not about the code inside or what your class is doing?

Comment: When I comment line with calling lambdas it reduce page loading to 2sec from 50sec.

Comment: But why do you think it is the `lambda` rather than the localization, `date_uzp` call (which is done twice BTW), `helper_method`, or even the ERB?

Comment: I have many types of lambdas(localization, number formating, ...), when i measure processing of each, time is almost constant.
Maybe it can be ERB problem, but how to overcome it?

Comment: When you will have to do the same thing, will your approach be different or same? I think I did it really well, but the speed of this approach really confuse me

Comment: `lambda { |row| helper_method row }` => `method(:helper_method)` - maybe you'll have to adjust the callee of `method`.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous functions aren't what's slow here. It's definitely the content of the function that's slow.

My favorite profiling tools are [ruby-prof](https://github.com/rdp/ruby-prof), [MiniProfiler](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Ruby), and puts-ing the built in `Benchmark.measure`.

Initial guesses are:

- expensive operations running in O(n)<sup>2</sup> time, since that's real easy to get in to when manipulating tables
- Date parsing. My experience is that some date parsing functions are fast, while others can be dog-slow (noticed the use of `date_uzp`; not sure about it specifically, just pointing it out as a possibility).
- Loading 1000 objects, then loading multiple associations (esp has-many) on each object. Loading that many activerecord objects can be really slow, especially if it increases the heap size / starts to trigger lots of garbage collection.

EDIT

Ok, another idea. Lambdas (and all blocks in ruby) create closures to maintain their context. Perhaps your strategy with lambdas is preventing large amounts of objects from getting garbage collected? I'm not exactly sure how to advise you refactor your code, though. The only way I know how to create a lambda without closure is like this:

```
def foo
  lambda {|row| helper_method row}
end
```

but there's got to be a better way to organize the code.

Comment: when I change content of lambdas to { |row| }, it still take 11sec to load. Something different has to be wrong...